# Get User in Service Class

Tags: php, symfony

I use Symfony2 and I install [ADesigns Bundle](https://github.com/adesigns/calendar-bundle). How can I get current logged user in `CalendarEventListener` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are as minimum 3 ways to do it. All of them described in official Symfony documentation at page http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/types.html.

To get current logged in user you need inject service `SecurityContext`. And then to get user object you need next code:

```
$securityContext->getToken()->getUser();
```